# How to mark an object for garbage collection by the GC (Garbage Collector)?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

In Java, is there a way to *mark* an object for garbage collection by the GC, during its next *clean up* cycle?

I've heard that setting an object to `null` no longer works.

Comment: Could you provide some links or documentation regarding why setting the object to `null` would not work? Of course, setting to `null` won't guarantee that it will be gc'ed ever either.

Comment: As soon as you eliminate all references to an object (for example by setting a reference to `null`) it becomes *eligible* for garbage collection.  You will not run out of memory before that memory is reclaimed (assuming it makes the difference between running out of heap space and not running out of heap).  When that GC actually happens is up to the VM.  Why does it concern you?

Comment: Its a concern because I'm dealing with a large amount of objects, that contain a fair amount of data. Allocation usually comes in the 1000s at a time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this question has been answered, but there are ways you can manipulate the way that the Java Garbage collector looks at your references.  You can do this through Soft References, Weak References, and Phantom References.  Take a look at the [java.lang.ref package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/ref/package-summary.html) for a better explanation.

Also here's a [nice sample](https://web.archive.org/web/20171015113149/http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com:80/egs/java.lang.ref/PhantomRef.html) to determine when a PhantomReference is about to be garbage collected:

> A phantom reference is used to determine when an object is just about to be reclaimed. Phantom references are safer to use than finalization because once an object is phantom reachable, it cannot be resurrected.

```
// Create the phantom reference.
ReferenceQueue rq = new ReferenceQueue();
PhantomReference pr = new PhantomReference(object, rq);

// Wait until the object is about to be reclaimed.
try {
    while (true) {
        Reference r = rq.remove();
        if (r == pr) {
            // The object is about to be reclaimed.
            // Clear the referent so that it can be reclaimed.
            r.clear();
        }
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
}
```

Comment: This was also interesting as well: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/05/04/understanding-weak-references

Answer (score 11):

No, you can't. What would you expect to happen if another variable had a reference to it?

Note that you can't set an *object* to null - you can only set a *variable* to null. If another variable still has a reference to the object, it will still not be eligible for garbage collection.

If you think you need to do this, that probably means you're misinterpreting your data - or that you may have a leak somewhere in your code (e.g. a list which you only ever add entries to, referenced by a static variable - those entries will never be eligible for garbage collection while the classloader is alive).

Each JVM has its own GC, but in Hotspot an object will be garbage collected next time the GC runs over the generation that object currently "lives" in (assuming it doesn't have a finalizer, which complicates things). If the object is in a "young" generation, that will probably happen quite soon - if it's in an "old" generation it may well take longer.

You may want to see the [Java 6 GC tuning documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) for more information, although of course things have moved on since then for OpenJDK 7 etc.

Comment: Well as I said in a comment I'm creating lots and lots of objects, and after I'm done processing, I don't need them anymore. I have a suspicion [supported by the profiler] that they aren't getting destoried.

Comment: @monksy: Then that suggests you've got a reference to them lurking somewhere, assuming the GC is running at all.

Comment: Thats my suspicion [The amount of objects currently initiated rarely ever drops it keeps growing] Are there any tools you would suggest that could help with this? I had to use Netbeans Profiler just to find this out.

Comment: @monksy: I'm afraid I don't have any advice there - I haven't used a Java profiler for ages :(

Comment: There are valid use cases where you need to do this. For example if you're writing an in memory cache, you might want to preiodically remove less used entries to avoid memory leaks, but instead of setting entry to null you can make it a soft reference, that way after cleanup object will still be available until garbage collection

Answer (score 4):

The Java Garbage Collector works with a mark and sweep method. This means from object that are known to still be in used all references are followed and the objects that are visited in that way are marked. In that way objects with no references at all are not marked and should be sure to be deleted. So you could ensure that all references to this object are removed, so that in the next turn of the Garbage Collector, the item is deleted.

Additionally you could use

```
Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
```

to indicate that the Garbage Collector should run. Note: you can't be sure that it really runs.

Comment: The garbage collector is not based on reference counting.  All modern JVMs are mark-and-sweep, most of them multi-generational.

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the implementation of the JVM?

Comment: No.  Reference counting will not allow you to correctly implement the Java language specification because of problems with reference cycles.  So not only does no existing JVM implementation use reference counting, none can and be conformant without also implementing an entirely different and correct collection mechanism.

Comment: @Mike Samuel. Ok I see. I changed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You heard wrong, but then again the description is wrong too.

You don't set an object to `null`, you set a variable to `null`.  If the variable can be used to get to an object, then the variable has a ***reference*** to the object.  Setting the variable to `null` is the same as the variable *"losing the reference"* to the object.

Once Java detects that an object, or a group of objects can't be reached by the running program, it will remove those objects from memory.  It won't remove them from memory one moment sooner, because if it did, and some other part of the program tried to use a reference to the object, then the reference would fail in a way that's not permissible in Java.

The trick is not to set just one reference to `null`, you have to set all the references that might have been made to `null`.  That's why it's important to consider each time you create a new reference, because you want to create them in such a manner that they will eventually be cleared (unless you want a memory leak).